# parsing python logs with logstash

Tags: python, logstash, logstash-configuration, elk, python-logging

I'm trying to set up a full logging pipeline as follows:
[python-logstash](https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash) -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana

from config.yml (logging configuration):

```
handlers
 logstash:
   class: logstash.LogstashHandler
   host: logstash
   port: 9010
```

from logstash.conf

```
input {
  udp {
      port => 9010
      codec => "json"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["***"]
      user => "***"
      password => "***"
  }
  stdout{}
}
```

that's the output i get:

```
logstash_1           | {
logstash_1           |     "@timestamp" => 2021-10-17T08:43:26.456Z,
logstash_1           |           "host" => "172.21.0.3",
logstash_1           |           "tags" => [
logstash_1           |         [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
logstash_1           |     ],
logstash_1           |        "message" => "\u0000",
logstash_1           |       "@version" => "1"
logstash_1           | }
```

This is my logging format:

```
format: '[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d : %(message) %(extra)s'
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly my logstash.conf is missing in order for it to work? Couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Do I have to build my own grok template?
If so, how can I get the extra fields properly parsed? (i used this source code for extracting extra fields: https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash/blob/7bd98c049533b101c2357c38135f21aaa441ebb3/logstash/formatter.py#L23)

Thanks in advance to all the helpers!

Comment: If your message is in a `json` format, your config is right, the error you got is because the message sent was not a json. This is the message logstash tried to parse `"message" => "\u0000"`, which of course is not a json. You need to check your code to see what is sending this kind of message and not your json message.